# Creating AppCloner in React Native

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-native, expo

This is My Code

getInstalledApplications  gets the All Packages Which are Installed in Mobile Device
cloneAndOpenAPKFile create clone and open in mobile but **it's open original File**

How Can i Do  this
also I want to use ApkTool that decompile the Application But I Can't able to install

How to Configure Apktool in android Device and How to use Please Guide me

```
 package com.dualspace; import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo; import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback; import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext; import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule; import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod; import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise; import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray; import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap; import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray; import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream; import java.io.File; import java.io.FileInputStream; import java.io.FileOutputStream; import java.io.IOException; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable; import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; import android.net.Uri; import android.util.Base64; import android.util.Log; import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
public class AppInfoModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
public static WritableArray applist;

public AppInfoModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
    reactContext = context;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "AppInfoModule"; // This is the name you will use in JavaScript
}
@ReactMethodpublic void getInstalledApplications(Promise promise) {try {//get a list of installed apps.PackageManager pm = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    WritableArray app_list = new WritableNativeArray();

    // ...

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        try {

            if (getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null) {
                WritableMap info = new WritableNativeMap();
                info.putString("name", packageInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                info.putString("packagename", packageInfo.packageName);
                info.putString("apk_path", packageInfo.sourceDir);
                try {
                    String apkPath = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageInfo.packageName, 0).sourceDir;
                    // info.putString("apkpath", apkPath);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // Handle exception if the package name is not found
                    System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

                }
                Drawable icon = packageInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    if (icon != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String base64Icon = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        info.putString("icon", base64Icon);
    }

                app_list.pushMap(info);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    promise.resolve(app_list); // Ensure you are resolving with the correct data type
} catch (Exception e) {
    promise.reject("ERROR", e.getMessage());
}}
@ReactMethodpublic void cloneAndOpenAPKFile(String packageName, String uniqueName, Promise promise) {try {PackageManager pm = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);

    String sourceApkPath = appInfo.sourceDir;
    String destinationFileName = uniqueName + ".apk"; // Unique name for the cloned APK
    String destinationPath = getReactApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + destinationFileName;

    // Clone the APK file
    cloneAPKFile(sourceApkPath, destinationPath, promise);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    promise.reject("PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND", "The specified package was not found");
} catch (Exception e) {
    promise.reject("UNKNOWN_ERROR", "An unknown error occurred");
}}
private void cloneAPKFile(String sourceFilePath, String destinationFilePath, Promise promise) {File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);File destinationFile = new File(destinationFilePath);

if (sourceFile.exists()) {
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

        // Open the cloned APK file without installing it
        openClonedAPK(destinationFilePath, promise);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        promise.reject("CLONE_ERROR", "Error cloning APK: " + e.getMessage());
    }
} else {
    promise.reject("SOURCE_NOT_FOUND", "Source APK file not found");
}}
private void openClonedAPK(String clonedFilePath, Promise promise) {try {File clonedFile = new File(clonedFilePath);if (clonedFile.exists()) {Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getReactApplicationContext(), getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", clonedFile);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        promise.resolve("APK file cloned and opened successfully");
    } else {
        promise.reject("CLONED_FILE_NOT_FOUND", "Cloned APK file not found");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    promise.reject("OPEN_ERROR", "Error opening cloned APK file: " + e.getMessage());
}}

@ReactMethod
public void openAPKFile(String filePath) {
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getReactApplicationContext(), getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.